# Too many characters in character literal with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I have this simple code WebForm2.aspx which runs an ajax request to get some data, but when I run this code, I'm getting this error: `Too many characters in character literal` What is going on?

The output I get is:

```
cccccccccccccccccccccccccc
```

---

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication24.WebForm2" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>FirstAjax</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var serviceURL = '/AjaxTest/FirstAjax';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: param = "",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });

            function successFunc(data, status) {     
                alert(data);
            }

            function errorFunc() {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What line is that error occurring on?

Comment: where do you get all of those `c`s?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your error is here:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: param = "", ///// HERE, try: data: {param:""}, but, I don't know what contains `param`
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is wit your data property:

```
data: param = "",
```

Use this instead

```
data: {param: ""},
```